# Why do I need to calculate the average for this problem?

Tags: puzzle, average, means

Say, the time zone of New Delhi is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of London.

I have the following data.
A flight departing at 10:00am from New Delhi lands at 02:30pm in London.
A flight departing at 05:00am from London lands at 08:30pm in New Delhi.

All times are in local time.

I’m required to calculate the flight duration in hours between New Delhi and London.

The answer goes as follows:

For New Delhi to London, the difference between 10:00am and 02:30pm is 4.5 hours.
Similarly, for London to New Delhi, the difference is 15.5 hours.

**Taking the average of these two — 4.5 and 15.5 hours gives me 10 hours, which is the required answer.**

The problem is, I do not understand this last step, as to why we are taking the average. In my head, my brain is stuck to the idea that we have to take the difference of 15.5 and 4.5, and the answer should be 11 hours (which is wrong). I’m sure the explanation is simple but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: More simply:  the first flight leaves at $4:30$ am London time, and arrives at $2:30$ pm London time, so the flight duration is $10$ hours.    You don't need the second flight at all, but:  it leaves at $5:00$ am London time and arrives at $3:00$ pm London time, which is again $10$ hours.

Comment: With no effect from prevailing winds???

Comment: @lulu Okay, but what if I didn’t know that New Delhi is 5.5 hours ahead of London? (That’s my mistake sorry, the problem I was doing didn’t mention the time difference. I have tried to create this data as an example of my own.)

Comment: @BernardMassé No, no effect. It is assumed that speed remains same for both journeys.

Comment: Ah, but then you need to explicitly make the unphysical assumption that the two travel times are the same (that assumption does not appear in your post).

Answer (score 1):

The "calculated" flight time going one way is the "real" flight time **plus** the time zone difference. In the opposite way it is the "real" flight time **minus** the time zone difference:
$$t_{N-L}=t_R-\Delta t\\t_{L-N}=t_R+\Delta t$$
Adding these two equations together you get $$t_{N-L}+t_{L-N}=2t_R$$
So: $$t_R=\frac{t_{N-L}+t_{L-N}}2$$
Notice that's independent of the time zone difference.

Comment: This explains it. Thank you!